# Difference between Spring on Azure and Azure Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-spring-cloud

I'm new to Azure and its services and I'm trying to sort out the differences. If one wants to deploy a Spring Boot app on Azure can this be done without using Azure Spring Cloud? Also, can Azure functions be integrated only with Azure Spring Cloud?

Here are the documentation pages for both:

[Spring on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/)

[Azure Spring Cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/)

Comment: When working with Azure Functions and you want to get all the benefits of Java/Spring Boot then yes you need to integrate it with Azure Spring Cloud (https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-azure)

Answer (score 1):

- **Spring on Azure** provides solution for integration with Azure Services such as Active Directory. It has nothing common with Spring Cloud project and is not targeted to the microservice architecture only.
- **Azure Spring Cloud** is a project that enables easy deployment of Spring Cloud based microservice applications to Azure while keeping the implementation platform agnostic. On top of that it offers solutions of components what is the microservice architecture about such as service discovery and registry, configuration management etc.

Comment: Do we at any point need thirdparty service mesh if we are using Azure Spring Cloud services to run our microservices. Is Service Mesh relevant when we are talking about Azure Spring Cloud Services?