# Difference between Azure App Service and Azure Spring Apps?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-spring-boot

If I want to deploy spring boot applications, how to choose between Azure App Service and Azure Spring Apps?

what are the various aspects that need to be considered before making the final decision?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy something? Share your effort and blockers if anywhere?

Comment: @NaveenSharma, no. No blocker. I want to know what cons and pros to choose between these two services for springboot apps.

Comment: Both Azure App service & Azure springs apps are PAAS offering solutions which can run spring boot applications. Based on your business requirement you need to choose which service suits for you.

Comment: -   [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview#why-use-app-service) is a fully managed hosting for web applications including websites and web APIs. These web applications may be deployed using code or containers. It is optimized for web applications and can be integrated with other services like Azure Container Apps or Azure Functions.

Comment: -  [Azure Spring App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/spring-apps/overview#why-use-azure-spring-apps) is considered for microservice architectures to run spring boot, spring cloud or any spring applications. This service manages the infrastructure of Spring applications so developers can focus on their code. Azure Spring Apps provides lifecycle management using comprehensive monitoring and diagnostics, configuration management, service discovery, CI/CD integration, blue-green deployments, and more.

Comment: if you're deploying a web application or API, you might want to consider Azure App Service. However, if you're working with Spring applications, particularly in a microservices architecture, Azure Spring Apps could be a better choice due to its tailored features and management capabilities.

Comment: Reference documents-
[Official MS doc-1 by MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1142822/what-is-difference-between-azure-app-service-and-a)

[Official MS doc-2 by MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1320408/how-to-choose-between-azure-spring-apps-and-app-se)

[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020289/difference-between-spring-on-azure-and-azure-spring-cloud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in similar dilemma from last few weeks. However, after spending few nights :) investigating about it, I deployed my spring boot app to Azure Spring Apps. Following were the same of the factors:

1. **Application Type**

   - **Azure App Service**: Works well for monolithic (single codebase) Spring Boot applications, web applications, and APIs.
   - **Azure Spring Apps**: Designed for microservice architectures built with Spring Boot, Spring Cloud, or any Spring application. Offers features like service discovery, configuration management, and built-in Spring expertise.
2. **Management and Control**

   - **Azure App Service**: Provides basic web app hosting features like scaling, auto-scaling, and continuous deployment. Requires manual configuration for Spring-specific functionalities.
   - **Azure Spring Apps**: Offers advanced Spring-focused management capabilities like configuration management, service binding, and Spring Boot health checks. Simplifies managing and scaling microservices.
3. **Development Expertise**

   - **Azure App Service**: Easier to set up and manage for general web applications, even with limited Spring knowledge.
   - **Azure Spring Apps**: Requires understanding of Spring concepts and microservices architectures for optimal utilization.
4. **Cost**

   - **Azure App Service**: Can be slightly cheaper for simple deployments due to its general-purpose nature.
   - **Azure Spring Apps**: Slightly more expensive due to its Spring-specific features and managed services.

Here's a quick table summarizing the key differences:

| Feature | Azure App Service | Azure Spring Apps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Application Type | Monolithic, web apps, APIs | Micro services (Spring Boot, Spring Cloud) |
| Management | Basic web hosting features | Spring-focused: configuration, service discovery, health checks |
| Development Expertise | Easier, requires less Spring knowledge | Requires Spring and micro services understanding |
| Cost | Slightly cheaper | Slightly more expensive |

***Recommendations:***

1. Use Azure App Service if:

   - You have a simple monolithic Spring Boot application or web app.
   - You have limited Spring expertise and prefer a simpler setup.
   - Cost is a major concern.
2. Use Azure Spring Apps if:

   - You have a microservices architecture built with Spring Boot or Spring Cloud.
   - You value advanced Spring management features and expertise.
   - You are comfortable with Spring and microservices concepts.

Ultimately, the best choice depends on your specific needs and priorities. Consider trying both services to see which one better suits your project requirements.

Following posts might also be helpful:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/faq?pivots=programming-language-java
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1320408/how-to-choose-between-azure-spring-apps-and-app-se

I hope this information helps you make an informed decision!

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy Spring Boot apps to App Service using the "Java SE" option. It is the easiest way to deploy your app in Azure. However, if your Spring apps requires any of the Spring services, try Azure Spring Apps instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean Spring services? Could you list some examples?

Comment: Azure Spring Apps is based of Spring cloud which is a collection of tools, frameworks and services to build microservices using Spring Boot platform.

For example, Eureka is the discovery service which is part of the Netflix Fx and is used by Spring Cloud.

Comment: In other words, if you don't have a microservices architecture and you don't need service discovery for example, then you just need App Service to power your Spring Boot application.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I accept this as an answer for your comments.